# How to forward session attribute set in Servlet to multiple JSPs?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

This is a method in the Servlet that calls a method from helper class(manages database operations) for verifying username and password and get the user-type(say admin,student...).

I am trying to get the usertype in httpSession and username in usernameSession.

```
private void loginUser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
    throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession();
        HttpSession usernameSession = request.getSession();
        //get selected username and password from login.jsp
        String username= request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        List<User> users = userUtilDB.checkUser(username, password);

        if(users.get(0).getUsername()==null)
        {
            httpSession.setAttribute("USER",null );
            request.setAttribute("USER",null );
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = 
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/redirect.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }
        else
        {

            httpSession.setAttribute("USER", users.get(0).getusertype());
     usernameSession.setAttribute("USERNAME",users.get(0).getUsername());
            List<User> userAll = userUtilDB.getUsers();
            request.setAttribute("USER_LIST", userAll);
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = 
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/redirect.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }
    }
```

Once I get the usertype, I am trying to redirect the user to appropriate page based on the usertype. On the redirect.jsp page this is how I am redirecting the usertype (for other user types too)

```
 <c:choose>
 <c:when test="${sessionScope.USER=='Student' }">
        <c:redirect url="/sample.jsp"/>
 </c:when>
 </c:choose>
```

On the sample.jsp page I am trying to print out the USERNAME session attribute like this:

```
<p>Welcome</p>:<c:out value="${sessionScope.USERNAME}" />
```

Is it possible for a session attribute set in Servlet to be forwarded from one JSP to another or accessed by multiple JSPs. I tried using `jsp:forward` as well, but I don't know how to pass the session attribute in `<jsp:param ... />`.

I am new to JSP programming. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: The session variables are shared about all pages of that domain. Check again once.